# Accessing json property twice

Tags: json, jackson, jackson2, jackson-databind

Consider the following `json` document:

```
{
  "a": {
    "one": "1",
    "two": "2"
  },
  "b": {
    "three": "3",
    "four": "4",
  }
}
```

I need to deserizlize it to the below POJO :

```
class Root{

 @JsonAlias({"a","b"})
 Node1 node1;

 @JsonAlias({"a","b"})
 Node2 node2;
}

class Node1 {
 String one;
 String three;
}
class Node2 {
 String two;
 String four;
}
```

It looks like the nested nodes (`a` and `b`) can only be traversed only once during `mapper.readValue`. Jackson populates only `node1` if I remove `@JsonAlias({"a","b"})` from `node2` and only `node2` if I remove `@JsonAlias({"a","b"})` from `node1`.

If I leave the annotaion on both, only one of them is populated.

Is this mapping supported? If not, what should be the workaround ?

I'm using jackson 2.9.1

Answer (score 1):

`@JsonAlias` only applies to the annotated field directly, in your case `node1`, `node2`. It will not cause Jackson to look for fields in both `Node1` and `Node2` classes. When parsing an object of class `Node1` for example it will expect fields `one` and `three` regardless of alias used and it can't find both. I'd recommend this set of annotations:

```
class Root {
    @JsonAlias("a")
    Node1 node1;

    @JsonAlias("b")
    Node2 node2;
}

class Node1 {
    String one;

    @JsonAlias("two")
    String three;
}

class Node2 {
    @JsonAlias("three")
    String two;

    String four;
}
```

And then you can parse the JSON doc in your question.

Comment: Thanks, @manos-nikolaidis, but my use case is more complex than I described . I end up with [jolt](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) transformation in the middle and then reading the transformed object with jackson into Root object. Thanks again for your answer.